# dot product of weight and input

Tags: machine-learning, dot-product

I am reading beginner's level ML books and it seems that everyone writes

```
output = np.dot(inputs, np.array(weights).T) + biases
```

It looks awkward to me since the equation is `y = wx + b`, not `y = xw + b`. A variable is written after its coefficient.

```
output = np.dot(weights, np.array(inputs).T) + np.array([biases]).T
```

Why not this? Is there a reason for that? or just a convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a convention picked up by the authors.
Even the way the variables(their dimensions) are initialised is another convention that leads to this.

Both ways are acceptable and are correct given you implement them correctly, that is the aim of the equation is satisfied.